# When is the LCD of two fractions the difference between their unit fractions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, circles, fractions

Sometimes it seems that the difference between their unit fractions is the LCD of two fractions. [one-twelfth equals one-eighteenth plus one thirty-sixth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eroH.png)

For example, the LCD between twelfths and eighteenths is the difference between their unit fractions. Using circle fractions: 1/12 = 30 degrees, 1/18= 20 degrees. Their difference is 30-20=10 degrees; which is 1/36ths of a circle.

[eighths and fourteenths don't seem to work that well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qc9d.png)

On the other hand sometimes this doesn't work at all - even though it seems kind of close such as a multiple of the LCD or something.

Ideas? Why would this work? When and under which circumstances? Thank you in advance, I will now make sandwiches and wait by my computer.

Origami 1729
Befriending numbers one at a time

Comment: What you are seeing seems to fit into the pattern of
$$\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n=\frac1{n(n-1)}$$
or its consequence (divide the above by $m$)
$$\frac1{m(n-1)}-\frac1{mn}=\frac1{mn(n-1)}.$$
In the former case $\gcd(n,n-1)=1$ whence their lcm is the product $n(n-1)$. In the latter case both get multiplied by that same factor $m$.

Comment: But you should also be advised about [what is expected from new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). Check out other questions in the tags you find interesting to learn what those pieces of advice really mean in practice.

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand it yet, but I will look at this.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $a<b$, and note that:

$$\frac1a-\frac1b=\frac{b-a}{ab} = \frac{b-a}{\gcd(a,b)\cdot\operatorname{lcm}\left(a,b\right)}$$

To see this, you need to know that the product of two numbers equals the product of their gcd and their lcm, which is a standard result in elementary number theory.

Anyway, if you want this result to equal: $$\frac1{\operatorname{lcm}\left(a,b\right)},$$

then you need the fraction to reduce just right, i.e., you need: $$b-a=\gcd(a,b).$$

With your examples, $18-12=6$, and $6$ is the gcd of $18$ and $12$. On the other hand, $14-8=6$, but the gcd of $14$ and $8$ is only $2$. That's why you're left with $3$ in the numerator of: $$\frac18-\frac1{14}=\frac3{56}.$$